# zoomband is displayed as lineseries when i add a stepseries to a chartXY?

Tags: lightningchart

i find that zoombandchart is displayed as lineseries when i add a stepseries to a chartXY,
what i expected is that the series in zoombandchart as stepseries, which is same as in chart,
so how to fixed this problem? here is my code:

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    StepOptions,
    UILayoutBuilders,
    UIElementBuilders,
    UIButtonPictures,
    UIBackgrounds,
    UIOrigins,
    emptyFill,
    emptyLine,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    SolidFill,
    Themes,
    createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = lcjs

const dashboard = lightningChart().Dashboard( {
     numberOfColumns: 1,
     numberOfRows: 4
 } )

 const chart = dashboard.createChartXY( {
     columnIndex: 0,
     columnSpan: 1,
     rowIndex: 0,
     rowSpan: 3
 })

 const zoomBandChart = dashboard.createZoomBandChart({
     columnIndex: 0,
     columnSpan: 1,
     rowIndex: 3,
     rowSpan: 1,
     axis: chart.getDefaultAxisX()
 })
zoomBandChart
        .setTitleFillStyle(emptyFill)
        
zoomBandChart.getDefaultAxisX()
        .setTickStrategy( AxisTickStrategies.Empty )
zoomBandChart.getDefaultAxisY()
        .setAnimationScroll(false)
 const line = chart.addStepSeries({mode:StepOptions.after})
 line.add([
     {x:0,y:1},
     {x:1,y:0},
     {x:2,y:1},
     {x:3,y:1},
     {x:4,y:1},
     {x:5,y:1},
     {x:6,y:1},
 ])
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: This issue is not resolvable from users side. All "line" type series are currently displayed as line series within `ZoomBandChart`. We'll note your issue down, and fix it in a near future minor release (I see no issue with modifying it so that `ZoomBandChart` also uses step series).

Comment: okay，i got what you mean,thanks. But I still want to add one more point (which you might need to noticed  when you fix this bug), in my project when the x-axis value of the data is equal step length , then the zoombandchart performance like stepseries, however,if the x-axis value of the data is not equal step, like [{x:1.y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:5,y:0},{x:6,y:0}], then zoombandchart is lineseries. it's really strange。